# How to style dynamically in lit?

Tags: css, web-component, lit-element, lit-html, lit

Good time
How to style dynamically in lit?
My main goal is to change the color of an element according to the user's input in the input element.

[My code screen shoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5R0J.png)

Comment: This will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71240044/how-to-ensure-css-class-styles-are-rendered-on-custom-html-elements/71241290#71241290

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use ‍`${}` in lit css tag function!

But you can select element and then change style

```js
import {html, css, LitElement} from 'lit';
import {customElement, property, query} from 'lit/decorators.js';

@customElement('dynamic-style')
export class DynamicStyle extends LitElement {
  static styles = css`
    label {
      color: #023047;
    }
  `;

  @property()
  color: string;

  @query('input') input: HTMLSelectElement | undefined;
  @query('label') label: HTMLSelectElement | undefined;

  render() {
    return html`
      <label for="color-input">HEX color: </label>
      <input id="color-input" placeholder="#023047" />
    `;
  }

  firstUpdated() {
    this.input.addEventListener('input', () => {
      this.label.style.color = this.input.value;
    });
  }
}
```

[lit playground](https://lit.dev/playground/#project=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-XG4gICAgICA8L2xhYmVsPlxuICAgIGA7XG4gIH1cblxuICBmaXJzdFVwZGF0ZWQoKSB7XG4gICAgdGhpcy5pbnB1dC5hZGRFdmVudExpc3RlbmVyKCdpbnB1dCcsICgpID0-IHtcbiAgICAgIHRoaXMubGFiZWwuc3R5bGUuY29sb3IgPSB0aGlzLmlucHV0LnZhbHVlO1xuICAgIH0pO1xuICB9XG59In0seyJuYW1lIjoiaW5kZXguaHRtbCIsImNvbnRlbnQiOiI8IURPQ1RZUEUgaHRtbD5cbjxoZWFkPlxuICA8c2NyaXB0IHR5cGU9XCJtb2R1bGVcIiBzcmM9XCIuL2R5bmFtaWMtc3R5bGUuanNcIj48L3NjcmlwdD5cbjwvaGVhZD5cbjxib2R5PlxuICA8ZHluYW1pYy1zdHlsZT48L2R5bmFtaWMtc3R5bGU-XG48L2JvZHk-XG4ifSx7Im5hbWUiOiJwYWNrYWdlLmpzb24iLCJjb250ZW50Ijoie1xuICBcImRlcGVuZGVuY2llc1wiOiB7XG4gICAgXCJsaXRcIjogXCJeMi4wLjBcIixcbiAgICBcIkBsaXQvcmVhY3RpdmUtZWxlbWVudFwiOiBcIl4xLjAuMFwiLFxuICAgIFwibGl0LWVsZW1lbnRcIjogXCJeMy4wLjBcIixcbiAgICBcImxpdC1odG1sXCI6IFwiXjIuMC4wXCJcbiAgfVxufSIsImhpZGRlbiI6dHJ1ZX1d)

Also read:
[Dynamic classes and styles | Lit Doc](https://lit.dev/docs/components/styles/#dynamic-classes-and-styles)

[Use CSS variable in Lit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59655232/18004491)

Comment: Why `color-input` class?

Comment: @mr.boris this class don't exists this is id